# Mono.CSharp: Evaluating math expressions

Tags: mono

I'm trying out Mono.CSharp's evaluator.
Why does this simple script work:

`int i=2,j=3;
(i*j);`

whereas this gives an error:

`int i=2,j=3;
i*j;`

saying "(1,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `i' could not be found. Are you
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: what version of Mono are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Mono.CSharp assembly within .NET 4.0

Comment: I didn't ask what version of .NET, I asked what version of Mono.CSharp

Comment: Assembly was built using source 2.11.1-535

Answer (score 3):

Mono.CSharp evaluator follows C# standard grammar rules. In your second example you are actually declaring local variable based on C# grammar.

It can be rewritten to this for easier human parsing

```
int i = 2, j = 3;
i* j;
```

Compiler parses second line as another variable declaration and tries to resolve "i" as a type before it applies pointer "*" to it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But these statements surprisingly do work:

int i=2;
i;

Why is no resolving as a type involved here?

Comment: I checked that further:
`i+j`
or `i/j`
work fine, only
`i*j`
gives that error. Could it be a bug in the built-in parser?